# Android - overlaid layout is forcing transparency on a button element

Tags: android, layout, transparency

I have my main home screen, but after it loads I want to display an overlaid wheel selector that will go away once a choice is made. Everything has gone well so far except that the submit button for the wheel selector is having some transparency forced upon it.

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried android:alpha to force it to be fully opaque but that has not had an effect. Here is the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:background="#faff67"
>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
 [ Not relevant? ]
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/wheelView" android:background="#CC000000"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">
        <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/deptWheel"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button_selectDept"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:alpha="1"
                    android:text="Submit"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas for what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: who is that overlay, DialogFragment or Popupwindow or what?

Comment: @Elltz That's the Relative Layout part of the XML file

Comment: change `Button` layout to  add `android:background="#FFFFFFFF"` and `android:textColor="#FF000000"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe throw in a background for the button:

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

Or change the color alpha:

```
android:color="#FF000000"
```

Perhaps both:

```
android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
```

Comment: Changing the background worked, but is there a way I can set it to the default without explicitly setting it to a pre-defined color?

Comment: Hmmm I don't know if this functionality exists. What you can do is settle on a certain shade of grey for the background that matches the top part, and then ensure that the text font color is black with no transparency.